# optimization rolling window pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series like this:

```
dist
0.02422
0.03267
0.04208
0.05229
0.06291
...
```

It has almost 200K row.
Is there a more efficient way to perform the following operation:

```
df["dist"].rolling(3000).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1] - x[x != 0].iloc[0] if x[x != 0].shape[0] else 0).dropna().max()
```

Pratically, I need to compute the difference between the first **non zero** and the last value of each window. The code above works, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do the same operation.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with you code is that it performs too many comparison against 0. Since the value in the `dist` column does not change, compare it once and reuse the result.

Here's on way to do it:

```py
# The scale of our problem
n = 200_000
window_size = 3_000

# Some simulated data. 20% of `dist` is zero
n_zero = int(n * 0.2)
dist = np.hstack([np.zeros(n_zero), np.random.uniform(0, 1, n - n_zero)])
np.random.shuffle(dist)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'dist': dist
})

# -----------------

# Convert dist to a numpy array. We do not need pandas series here
dist = df['dist'].to_numpy()

# Find the indexes of all non-zero elements. nz = non-zero
nz_index, = np.nonzero(dist)

# For each row in `dist`, find the first non-zero value within
# the next `window_size` rows. Return NaN if no such value
# can be found.
dist_nz = np.empty_like(dist)
idx = 0
for i in range(len(dist)):
    idx += 1 if i > nz_index[idx] else 0
    dist_nz[i] = dist[nz_index[idx]] if idx < len(nz_index) and (idx - i < window_size) else np.nan

(dist[window_size-1:] - dist_nz[:-window_size+1]).max()
```

This completes in 0.3s compared to 2m 13s of the original.